# Why does vfill not work inside a beamer column?

Tags: beamer, spacing, columns

I recently tried to set up a quartered page layout in `beamer` (separate question might follow) and `\vfill` failed in a column environment.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{\textwidth}
                Blublub

                \vfill

                Blablabla

                Blublub

                \vfill

                Blablabla
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What is the problem here?
How can I fix or circumvent it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `column` environment is using a `minipage` environment internally which doesn't has a predefined height like the whole frame has. The `\vfill` macro fills out the rest of given the vertical space. Because there is no height defined it does nothing. You have to define the height, e.g. using `\vbox` as shown below:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{\textwidth}
                \vbox to .8\textheight{%
                Blublub

                \vfill

                Blablabla
                Blublub

                \vfill

                Blablabla
                }%
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just finishing up my explanation when I got notified about Herbert's answer. Using `minipage` might be better than `\vbox`. I just thought not posting my almost finished explanation would be a waste.

Comment: Also your answer needs to tweak `.8 \textheight`, similar to Herbert's answer, which is ok for a single case, but somehow a hack.

Comment: @Turion: Yes, I forgot to mention that the height must be set manually depending on the style. I don't know if there is a length register which gives you the total usable height. It depends on the height of the frame header which is different for every style and I don't think the styles are calculating it for you.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Can you explain why using `minipage` superior to your `vbox` solution?

Comment: @Dror: I said *might be*, not *is*.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Can you explain why using `minipage` _might be_ superior to your `vbox` solution?

Answer (score 17):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}{bar}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{\textwidth}
          \minipage[c][0.7\textheight][s]{\columnwidth}
                Blublub

                \vfill

                Blablabla

                Blublub

                \vfill

                Blablabla
         \endminipage
        \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you! But how did you choose the factor 0.7 in front of `\textheight` in the minipage declaration?
It seems I'm looking for a `\beamerbodyheight` or `\columnheight`.

Comment: I forgot about the name of the possible height, the reason why I choosed a fraction of `\textheight`